# Setting URL in an Android application?

Tags: android, http, url, post, ip

Within my `Android` application I want to connect to a `PHP` file on my server/web host. Currently I cannot `POST` data to the `PHP` file, I think I am passing the URL in an *incorrect format*.

Using a Google URL as an example, would this be correct in order to establish the path to my PHP file?

```
URL url = new URL("http://74.125.224.72/myFile.php");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have an extra space in your URL

```
URL url = new URL("http://74.125.224.72 /myFile.php");
```

must be

```
URL url = new URL("http://74.125.224.72/myFile.php");
```

**EDIT** You can also use the android [Uri](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class and build it using the `Uri.Builder`

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .authority("74.125.224.72")
    .appendPath("myFile.php")
    .build();
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Doe the URL look ok otherwise?

Comment: It seems ok. I edited my answer to show you the use of Uri.Builder.

Comment: Thanks, Can I also use the actualy web address? Using Google as an Exmaple: URL url = new URL("http://www.mywebsitename/myFile.php");